# How can I get list of counties in a route from OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, nominatim, mapquest

I have a route created by MapQuest Open Directions Service. I would like to get a list of all counties that route runs through. Does anyone know if this is possible?

I have tried figuring out if I can do it with Overpass or Nominatim, but  haven't found any way to do it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this topic can have hints for you?
https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/47989/how-to-get-info-about-administrative-levels-from-single-coordinate-in-overpass

it is about the is_in feature of the overpas-api.

Comment: Thanks! is_in gives me what I want for one set of coordinates, but how can I get it to give me the counties for a route? I've tried reading, but haven't figured out how to send in a list of coordinates to is_in.

Comment: @thomfre: this is currently not supported, you can only provide one coordinate. Only in case you've already got an existing OSM relation, `is_in` will return a list of all countries this relation is in: `rel(1075081);>;is_in;area._[boundary=administrative][admin_level=2];out;`.


At this time, you can only chain several `is_in`:  `(is_in(59.68,16.77);is_in(59.63,15.77);is_in(58.68,15.77););area._[boundary=administrative][admin_level=2];out;` - this is likely to be a bit slow.



I suggest to create an enhancement request here: https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues

Comment: Issue was created: https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/253

Comment: I found another tool but I am not sure whether it will help you: http://www.openstreetmap.org/user/ruthmaben/diary/37865 reports about "POIs along a route" ... not a direct help, but maybe you can adapt that technique to divide a route in parts and then dtermine in what state it is.